# Meaning of "sufficient"

Tags: logic

> The range of the heights of the female students in a certain class is
> 13.2 inches, and the range of the heights of the male students in the class is 15.4 inches. Which of the following statements individually
> provide(s) sufficient additional information to determine the range of
> the heights of all the students in the class? Indicate all such
> statements.
>
> "A The tallest male student in the class is 5.8 inches taller than the
> tallest female student in the class.
>
> "B The median height of the male
> students in the class is 1.1 inches greater than the median height of
> the female students in the class.
>
> "C The average (arithmetic mean)
> height of the male students in the class is 4.6 inches greater than
> the average height of the female students in the class.

What does the term "sufficient" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sufficient means that, taking just the given piece of information plus the information in the question, it is possible to fully determine the range of the heights of all the students in the class. You should maybe [read up on how](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) the terms “sufficient” and “necessary” are used linguistically to represent $\implies$ and $\impliedby$ respectively.

In this case, the question basically asks that, given the information in the question preamble, which of the following are true:

That $A \implies$ you can tell the range of the heights of all the students.

That $B \implies$ you can tell the range of the heights of all the students.

Or, that $C \implies$ you can tell the range of the heights of all the students.